# Orders in number fields

Tags: number-fields, nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a degree $n$ extension of ${\mathbb Q}$ with ring of integers $R$. An order in $K$ is a subring with identity of $R$ which is a ${\mathbb Z}$-module of rank $n$.

Question: Let $p$ be an unramified prime in $K$. Is it true that the number of orders in $R$ of index equal to $p^r$, for some natural number $r$, is less than or equal to the number of subrings with identity of ${\mathbb Z}^n$ of index equal to $p^r$?

Nathan Kaplan and I need this fact for $n=5$ in a project where we are trying to find asymptotic formulae for the number of orders of bounded index in a given quintic field.

We've been staring at Jos Brakenhoff's [thesis](https://openaccess.leidenuniv.nl/bitstream/handle/1887/14539/proefschrift-brakenhoff.pdf?sequence=2) for a while, but I haven't gotten anywhere. Any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Added in edit: Here is an elementary reformulation of this problem. Let $r(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients. Then show that for any natural number $a$ in order to maximize the number of subrings of $({\mathbb Z}/p^a {\mathbb Z})[x]/(r(x))$ of a given index, the polynomial $r(x)$ has to be a product of linear factors modulo $p$.

Update: In a soon-to-be-posted preprint Nathan Kaplan, Jake Marcinek, and I have proved an asymptotic formula for the number of orders in a given quintic field of bounded discriminant, using an argument independent of the above question. We can also give non-trivial upper bounds for a general number field. I'm now convinced the answer to the question is yes, but I still don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Who voted to close? And why?

Comment: Is it obvious that the elementary reformulation is the same, given that one is restricted to $p$ unramified and the other is not?

Comment: It is clear that this question can be studied locally at $p$. In other words, this depends only on $R \otimes \mathbb Z_p$, so it depends only on $K \otimes \mathbb Q_p$, which is just a product of $p$-adic fields.

Comment: In our work we only need this for unramified primes. 

Comment: Have you tried (probably you have) writing down a binary $n$-ic form and playing the same game as in Theorem 9 to Lemma 13 of Bhargava, Shankar, and Tsimerman's paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.0672.pdf ? This doesn't "just work", the details are much messier, but since you need something weaker I wonder if it is possible to salvage the result you are looking for?

Comment: I found a paper by Melanie Wood which might be relevant, although I did not check it carefully: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.5508v1.pdf

Comment: The $r=1$ case can be handled as follows. Each order in $R$ of index $p$ is uniquely determined by its image in $R/pR$. Now $R/pR$ is an \'etale $k := \mathbf{F_p}$-algebra of rank $n$ as $p$ is unramified. Now the set of such rings injects into the set of index $p$ $k$-subalgebras of $R/pR \otimes_k \overline{k} \simeq \overline{k}^n$. The latter set is a combinatorial object (it's the set of surjective maps from an $n$-element set to an $(n-1)$-element set), and can be bounded above by the set of index $p$ subrings of $\mathbf{Z}^n$. 

Comment: Thanks everyone. You can actually count the number of subrings of index $p$. Namely, if $r(x) \mod p$ has $u$ factors of degree $1$ and $w$ factors of degree $2$, and the rest of higher degrees, then the number of subrings of ${\mathbb Z}/p{\mathbb Z}[x]/(r(x))$ of index $p$ is ${u \choose 2} + w$. 